# Using OpenAM OAuth2 with MVC4 and OAuthWebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, openam

Before trying [MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383708/using-openam-with-mvc5), I had a go at using OpenAM with MVC4, with slightly better results. I need to authenticate from an asp.net application using OpenAM, and don't fancy the Fedlet route - I can see anybody else who has ever tried that

So, [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) was my starting point. This shows how to use Google and Facebook, and it works a treat. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx) goes on to show how to use other providers. I'm using OpenAM with OAuth2, so created "OpenAMClient", inheriting from DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client, and registered this in AuthConfig.RegisterAuth:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new OpenAMClient("consumerKey", "consumerSecret"));
```

This is great, because it now appears automatically on the login page, and pretty much worked perfectly until I started to use it for authentication. In the GetServiceLoginUrl override, I constructed a path to my OpenAM server, appending the returnURL that had been generated by the application and passed in as a parameter:

```
protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
{
    var response =
        string.Format(
            "http://localopenam.hibu.com:9080/openam_10.1.0/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type=code&scope=email&redirect_uri={1}",
            _consumerKey, returnUrl);
    return new Uri(response);
}
```

This got me to my OpenAM server login page, but after authenticating, I got an error saying that the redirection URI wasn't acceptable. Debugging the code, I can see that the ReturnURL starts off in the ExternalLoginResult as "/Account/ExternalLoginCallback", but by the time it reaches GetServiceLoginUrl, it has become:

```
http://localhost:60448/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=OpenAM&__sid__=12e299cbac474b60a935f946f69d04a8
```

OpenAM isn't having any of that, as the "sid" parameter is dynamic, and it doesn't seem to acccept wildcards - it won't allow the returnURL provided by OAuthWebSecurity.

As a workaround, I intercept the ReturnURL, and switch to a new AccountController method:

```
protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
{

    var workingUrl = "http://localhost:60448/Account/OpenAMCallback";
    var response =
        string.Format(
            "http://localopenam.hibu.com:9080/openam_10.1.0/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type=code&scope=email&redirect_uri={1}",
            _consumerKey, workingUrl);
    return new Uri(response);
}
```

I add `http://localhost:60448/Account/OpenAMCallback` as a redirectURL in OpenAM, then added AccountController OpenAMCallback:

```
    public ActionResult OpenAMCallback(string code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code  );
        //use the code to get the token, then user details  etc
        return RedirectToLocal(null);
    }
```

This is great, because from here I get the access code, so I can make more requests for the token, get all the allowed user details, all of that kind of thing, but ... I'm jealous of the original ExternalLoginCallback method I've subverted away from, that all the other cool authentication servers use. I want to use OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication and OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData, but VerifyAuthentication is coming back as null, so that stops that party

I can use http://dotnetopenauth.net/ and do it by hand, but I'd rather use a framework so there's less to maintain. Am I missing something obvious, or is OAuthWebSecurity not really up to this so I should stick with dotnetopenauth?

thanks